# Vim editing *diff file*, updating diff ranges automatically

Tags: vim, diff

Suppose I generate diff of my project before commit, let say using svn. Having one diff for all files in project is a very nice way to review changes before committing them. However sometimes I wish to edit those changes without reopening each file, simple edit the diff and have it reapplied. So I have made such key map(I have setup svn diff to use unified format with fair amount of surrounding lines):

```
map scde :w! tmpdiff<cr>:!svn revert -R .<cr>:!patch -p0 <tmpdiff<cr>
```

It works, but only partially; you can edit added lines, but if you mark lines as removed or want to add another line you get some trouble since specified diff ranges do not match with actual text present in the diff. One can update them for simple changes like adding a line, however it is tedious and quickly gets complicated if you make more sophisticated changes. Is there a way to edit diff in so that range would automatically update correctly? I have found that emacs has some diff mode for this(however I have not tried it), however I was unable to find solution for my needs using vim. Maye there someone can give some suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at [`rediff`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/editdiff1.html). It automatically fixes the offsets within a patch file.

Comment: Indeed rediff seems like a tool for such situation. Thanks.
Just a note for others why might try this. After editing a diff and rediff'ing you might need to set different fuzz when patching (option -F).